# Lxde raspberry pi autostart variable not working

Tags: linux, bash, chromium, lxde

I cant use my variables in the next autostart

```
@$x="https://mypage.com/#"

@y=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial | cut -d ' ' -f 2`

@chromium-browser --incognito $x$y
```

the y variable get the serial number

When chromium opens I get %24x%24y in urll browser. What I want is https://mypage.com/#myserialnumber .

**Edit 20/03/2020**

First I created the file

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ touch vars.sh
```

Then change the file

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ nano vars.sh


#!/bin/bash
x="https://mypage.com/#"
y=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
f=$x$y
```

I change the autostart to this

```
@source ~/.vars.sh
@chromium-browser --incognito $f
```

but the result is the same %24f in the urll browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autostart file does not work like that.

Instead each command runs under its own subshell **simultaneously**.
Therefore, your chromium command doesn't know those variables even exist.

### To fix:

Put those 3 commands in a bash script (*.sh) file, make it executable, and put the path to the script in your autostart file.

## Example script at /home/pi/Desktop/myscript.sh:

```
x="https://mypage.com/#"
y="$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial | cut -d ' ' -f 2)"
@chromium-browser --incognito $x$y
```

To make executable, run `chmod +x /home/pi/Desktop/myscript.sh` in a terminal.
To run on boot, put `@/home/pi/Desktop/myscript.sh` in the autostart file.

Comment: Maybe the answer is to obvious but Im totally new and everything I know is from google. I edit the question could you give me more advice please.

Comment: That won't work either. You have to put **all 3 commands** in your .sh file. INCLUDING THE CHROMIUM LINE.

Comment: I included to the bash script   chromium-browser --incognito $f   but now nothing opens

Comment: Run your script in the terminal. That way you can see any errors that show up.

Comment: I ran the bash script in terminal like this source vars.sh and works perfect now I only need that autostart run the code. I think the problem is in autostart @source ~/.vars.sh   I created the autostart with the command sudo nano /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

Comment: IDK why you need `source` in the path to the script. 1. Make sure you changed the file properties to be executable. 2. Give the full path to the script in autostart. I would put this in autostart: @/home/pi/vars.sh

Comment: @Botspot Can you give a simple example bash script in your answer and make it executable with `chmod`?

Comment: @Ingo just did :)

Comment: @Botspot because Im a complete noob. Thanks both of you.